# Does WebDriver impose a maximum number of drivers running at one time?

Tags: java, concurrency, webdriver

As stated, does WebDriver impose a maximum number of drivers running at one time?

The reason I ask this is that I am running not just one, but rather a pool of Threads, each of which executes a set test scenario, and then records the test result and time once all threads have completed.

If I run:
1...fine,
2...fine,
3...fine,
4...fine,
5+...some return "fail" even though each scenario is the exact same!

Strange enough is that it will return results similar to:

```
    Test #1   Pass   13s
    Test #2   Pass   19s
    Test #3   Fail    0s
    Test #4   Pass    8s
    Test #1   Pass   11s
```

So apparently, the thread executed and then completed in 0s.
And probably the strangest is that the log file (there is one file for each thread) shows that the thread started and created the driver, however shortly after (perhaps when the driver was started) the thread was interrupted and/or killed.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better directed to the webdriver support forum? http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers?pli=1

Comment: I am assuming that its not possible for the test to complete in under 1 second.  What error is produced? Without that you are likely to leave us all scratching out heads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your responses, but I found my answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/dc392ed42d3090f4?fwc=1) regarding the exception I received: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms`

According to the link, if there are too many Firefox instances that are unresponsive/weakly responsive within 45 seconds, the driver throws this exception.

In other words, I'm running too many at one time.

Comment: We have the exact same issue but haven't seem to find a solution. Our Main processes implements a pool of threads that call the Macro WebDrivers. Once that happens we are getting the same error you have below: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms How did you fix it or what was your work around?

Comment: I didn't have any fix, rather our team decided that it was not required of us to run more than small number of instances at the same time.